# Search multiple words in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a HTML form to allow users to find entries in a database table:

```
   <form action="controller.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="word" id="word">
```

The table in my database has a column called keywords that contains multiple values, and so I use a SELECT query to select all rows that have any keywords that match what the user typed into the form. So controller.php contains this query:

```
$word= $_GET['word'];

$query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.keywords LIKE '%{$word}%
```

This works fine, except if a user types more than one word into the search box. How do I alter this  such that, when a user types more then one word into the search box, it will return all rows that have *either* of the users words in its keywords column.

i.e, user searches "apples oranges", and the query returns all rows that have *either* "apples" or "oranges" in their keywords field.

Comment: Explode your searchword and loop through the array result in which you create multiple LIKE statements and append to your query.

Comment: What if you use full text search? This could order the results in google like order (by relevance).

Answer (score 4):

You can try with -

```
$words = explode(' ', $word);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.keywords IN (".implode(',', $words).")";
```

Or -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE";
$conds = array();
foreach ($words as $val) {
    $conds[] = "table.keywords LIKE '%".$val."%'";
}
$query .= implode(' OR ', $conds);
```

The checks can be added if required.

Comment: where are the wildcards? :)

Comment: Needs to be an exact match.

Comment: yup. for this case it needs to be exact match. Also the query can be generated accordingly.

Comment: @Daan updated the answer. Now the wildcards will work.

Comment: Thanx sgt, worked perfectly. Just out of interest, what is a wildcard?

Comment: `'%aaa%'` are the wildcards.

Comment: OK but i've run into a problem with your solution. If any blank spaces are left before or after the search term in the form, e.g. " orange" or "orange ", the query becomes

(WHERE table.keywords LIKE '%orange% OR table.keywords LIKE %%)

Or if more than one space is left in between 2 search terms, e,g "orange  apple", the query becomes  

(WHERE table.keywords LIKE '%orange% OR table.keywords LIKE %% OR table.keywords LIKE '%apple%')

The result is that it returns every entry in my table regardless of whether it contains the keyword apple or orange.

Comment: `trim()` will be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
$words = explode(' ', $_GET['word']);
$regex = implode('|', $words);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.keywords REGEXP '{$regex}'";
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code and work fine

```
    $regcond = trim($_GET['word']);
    $regcond = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $regcond); //change how many space beetwen word to one space
    $regcond = trim($regcond);
    $regcond = str_replace(" ",".+",$regcond); // change all space to .+ for search with regex
    $final_cond = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.keywords REGEXP "' . $regcond . '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$string = array_map(function(&$word){
    return "+".$word."*";
},$words);

$term = implode(" ",$string);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(column_name) AGAINST('{$term}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` command is good for one-word string. For advanced searching in database use `FULLTEXT` search.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Adding a fulltext index doesn't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As in SQL unable to search for single name try splitting the name based on spaces like i.e Heavens Road and appending to string i.e (`'%Heavens%'`) OR (`%Road%`) in final query.

```
SELECT id, gps, street_name 
FROM streets 
WHERE street_name LIKE ('%Heavens%') OR (%Road%)
```

e.g if more terms are then `LIKE (%1term%) OR (%2term%) OR (%3term%) OR (%4term%)`

Answer (score 0):

regular expression does it for me.

```
$str = $_GET['words']; 
$commonwords = 'a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,this,are';// you dont want to search for these common words

$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);

$str = explode(" ", $str);

foreach($str as $value){
  if(!in_array($value, $commonwords)){ // remove the common words from search

    $query[] = $value;
  }
}   

$query = implode(" ", $query);// generate coma separated values 

$str2 =(explode(" ",$query));// convert the values to an array
$Words = implode('|',array_values($str2)).'';// generate values to be searched and make regex

"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `keywords` REGEXP '$Words'"
```

Works for me where the user search for more than one product each separated by a space. user does not have to type full words

Answer (score 0):

Here's my PHP solution where the search string contains multiple keywords, can be in any order, may be separated by multiple spaces, may have repetitions, must be ranked on how many keywords found, and is sql injection safe. Assume table is called Topics with an ID of TopicID, text in column TopicText and keywords in column Keywords, and your mySQL connection is $dbConn

```
//convert search string to lowercase - will do case insensitive search later
$words = trim(strtolower($_GET['k']));
//remove punctuation and wildcards
$words = str_replace(array('*', '?', '-', '.', '/', '(', ')', '+', '&'), '', $words);
//turn the string into an array of unique words
$words = array_unique(explode(' ', $words));
//strip the words we are not interested in
$stopWords = array('', '*',  '?', 'a', 'about', 'an', 'and','are', 'as', 'at', 'be', 'by', 'for', 'from', 'how', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'that', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'was', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'who', 'will', 'with');
foreach($stopWords as $word) {
    if (($key = array_search($word, $words)) !== false) unset($words[$key]);
}
//build SQL statement
$sql =  "select TopicText, Score from (select TopicID,  0";
foreach($words as $word) {
    if($word>'') $sql .= "+if(Keywords regexp '" . $dbConn->real_escape_string($word) . "',1,0)";
}
$sql .=  " as Score from Topics) T join Topics TT on TT.TopicID = T.TopicID where T.Score>0 order by Score desc";
```

If you don't have a column with keywords, one could use the TopicText column as the regexp target above.

Answer (score -4):

```
  $word= $_GET['word'];
if (strpos($word, ' ') !== FALSE) {
    $wordArr = explode(' ', $word);
    $where = '';
    foreach ($wordArr AS $word) {
        $where .= " table.keywords LIKE '%{$word}%' OR";
    }
    $where = trim($where, 'OR');
} else {
    $where = "table.keywords LIKE '%{$word}%' ";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $where";
echo $query;
```

Comment: The amount of words typed is dynamic your code is NOT.

Comment: if it contain more than 2 words?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a flexible solution at all :(

Comment: Fortunately there IS a flexible way to loop over the words and construct the query.

Comment: @Daan, sgt BOSE,  jeromegamez, bksi . Thanks for the feedback, Check the edited answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do here??

Comment: @  Sameer Shaikh Check now